# ¿Cómo añadir opacidad a una imagen?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo esta imagen de enlace que va en el Header, y nos lleva a la pagina de inicio, sin embargo no se como hacer para que cuando se pase el mouse sobre la imagen cambie ya sea la opacidad o se ponga más oscura, como  para que se sepa que es un botón o enlace, trate de hacerlo en la manera que les muestro pero no funciona.

```css
header a img:hover {
   opacity: 1.0;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html">
      <img class="center-block logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/Mnq96zk.png">
      </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Puse esa imagen pero quizá no sea la más apropiada para probar la opacidad. Procura poner una que si valga y no un recurso local como tenias. Un saludo

Comment: Opacidad es algo **no** transparente. `opacity:1` indica que la opacidad está al máximo, por lo tanto no hay tansparencia, `opacity: 0` sería totalmente transparente y no se vería el elemento

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a ensayarlo, gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando indicas que la opacidad sea de 1 significa que la imagen se va a ver de la misma forma que si no la modificaras.

Los rangos van de 0 a 1 siendo `0 = invisible` y `1 = visibilidad total`. En este caso he añadido una opacidad de un 0.5 para que se vea un efecto cuando pasas por encima de la imagen.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
header a img:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html">
      <img class="center-block logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/Mnq96zk.png">
      </a>
  </div>
</header>
```